# Address Out of range mips

Tags: assembly, mips

Hello i am trying to implement the mccarthy 91 function in assembly code.  When i run my code it assembles with no errors but when i enter a value for n the program gets runtime exception address out of range.  I've looked over my code and i cant find out why this keeps happening.  The error happens on

```
 sw $ra, 0($sp)     #save return address
```

Code trying to implement:

```
 def mcc91(n):global countcount += 1     
       if n > 100:     
          n -10
       else: 
          return mcc91(mcc91(n + 11))
```

Code:

```
main:
    #Build stack frame
    subu $sp, $sp, 32   #stack frame is 32 bytes long
    sw $ra, 20($sp)     #save return address
    sw $fp, 16($sp)     #save old frame pointer
    addiu $fp, $sp, 28  #set up frame pointer

    li $v0, 4       #system call code for print_str
    la $a0, prompt      #address of string to print
    syscall         #print the string

    li $v0, 5       #system call for read_int
    syscall         #read n
    move $t0, $v0       #and store it
    move $a0, $t0       #move the argument

    move $t9, $zero     #clear the count
    jal mcc         #call the mcc function

    move $s0, $v0       #get the answer returned from mcc and save it

    li $v0, 4       #system call code for print_str     
    la $a0, ans     #address of string to print
    syscall         #print the ans string

    move $a0, $s0       #move answer to get ready to print
    li $v0, 1       #system call code for print_int
    syscall         #print answer

    li $v0, 4       #system call code for print_str
    la $a0, count       #address of string to print
    syscall         #print count string

    move $a0, $t9       #get count ready to print
    li $v0, 1       #system call code for print_int
    syscall         #print count

    #tear down stack frame
    lw $ra 20($sp)      #restore return address
    lw $fp, 16($sp)     #restore frame pointer
    addiu $sp, $sp, 32  #pop stack frame
    li $v0, 10      #exit program

mcc:
    addi $t9, $t9, 1    #increment global count

    #Build stack frame
    subu $sp, $sp, 12   #stack frame is 32 bytes long
    sw $ra, 0($sp)      #save return address
    sw $a0, 4($sp)      #save n

    bgt $a0, 100, base  #base call

    addi $a0, $a0, 11   #add 11 to n
    jal mcc         #mcc91(n+11)
    move $a0, $v0       #n = mcc91(n + 11)
    jal mcc         #do outer recursion
    j done

base:
    subi $a0, $a0, 10   #subtract 10 from n

done:               #result is in $v0
    #tear down the stack frame
    lw $ra, 0($sp)      #restore $ra
    lw $a0, 4($sp)      #restore n
    addiu $sp, $sp, 12  #pop stack
    jr $ra          #return to caller
```

Comment: Sounds like a stack overflow to me (just guessing and running), will have a look at it. Your stack structure looks a bit illogical. Reserving too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the line where things go wrong:

```
move $a0, $v0       #n = mcc91(n + 11)
```

You're trying to move the return value from a previous call to `mcc` into `$a0`, but you never actually place the return value in `$v0`. So you'll need to change this part:

```
base:
    subi $a0, $a0, 10   #subtract 10 from n
```

into:

```
base:
    subi $v0, $a0, 10   # return n - 10
```

I tried the program with that change and got answer=93,count=1 for n=103, and answer=91,count=5 for n=99, which seems correct to me.

Comment: thanks for your help! that solved the problem cant believe i missed that lol